# Php if($_POST) vs if(isset($_POST))

Tags: php, post, isset

I have a simple form as demonstrated below:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

When I try to receive data sent from this form via `if($_POST)`, I fail, but when try with `isset`, I success.

```
if($_POST){
  echo 'a'; //Doesn't print anything.
}
if(isset($_POST)){
  echo 'b'; //Prints 'b'
}
```

I guess the reason behind it is missing name attribute in my form input, but I can't understand why `if($_POST)` and `isset($_POST)` react different ways in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`isset` *determine if a variable is set and is not NULL*. `$_POST` will always be set and will always be an array.

Without `isset` you are just testing if the value is truthy. An empty array (which `$_POST` will be if you aren't posting any data) will not be truthy.

Comment: For comparisons php will convert (type cast) the ´$_POST` array to a boolean value of true or false. If an array is empty it will be converted to `false` and to `true` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

isset determines if a variable is set and not NULL, see the manual: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

while `if($_POST)` checks `$_POST` for being true.

in your case, `$_POST` will always be set. If doing that with other variables not related to a form, keep in mind that checking for `if($var)` without knowing if it is set or not, will throw a notice. Checking `if(isset($var))` will not throw a notice.

Unrelated to your question: if you want to know if there is data inside your `$_POST` array you could try working with `count($_POST)`, see:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `$_POST` is an array of inputs names/values pairs, and in your form no input has any name, therefore it is an empty array (evaluating to false). You can verify it by `var_dump($_POST)`.

Try to add a name to text input to access its value:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="somename" />
  <input type="submit" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

The major difference is **isset** determine variable is set and is not null for **$_POST** is not work here because you are not define here input name. The **$_POST** consider an array of inputs name/values pairs.