# Php Error with IF statements & validation

Tags: php

I am trying to validate an input using a form, through the use of an if statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['weekly-rate']))
{
    $weekly_rate = $_POST['weekly-rate'];
    if(!isset($_POST['weekly-rate']))
    {
        $error_messages[]= 'Weekly rate was not set';

    }
    else
     {
        $weekly_rateOK = true;
    }

}
else
{
    $error_messages[] = 'Weekly rate was not set...';
}
```

When I run this it gives doesn't give me the output I want, which is Weekly rent was not set. Am I incorrect in thinking that

```
if(!isset($_POST['weekly-rate']))
{
    $error_messages[]= 'Weekly rate was not set';`
```

Means, if an input is not set, run the error message, weekly rate was not set.

However all I receive is nothing

Comment: Don't check if it is set. It's *always* set. Check to see if it has a *value*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php if($\_POST) vs if(isset($\_POST))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609086/php-if-post-vs-ifisset-post)

Comment: John Conde, this is not true, it is not *always* set... It is only set, if the submitted browser sets it... If there was no form/whatever input before, the browser can not know this

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of `isset()` is correct. However, the form always posts the field back to your backend code which triggers `isset()` to be true all the time. You may look at using `empty()` instead.

A simplified version would look like this

```
$weekly_rateOK = !empty($_POST['weekly-rate']);
if (!$weekly_rateOK) {
    $error_messages[] = 'Weekly rate was not set...';
}
```

You may need to add an integer check if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a text input/select with a name, then the input/select is always posted and is set, but with an empty string. If it is a checkbox or radio buttons, then they will be set only if the checkbox is checked or a radio button is selected.

I have written a sample validation function, inspired by [Laravel](https://laravel.com). You can check it [here](https://3v4l.org/pfP2n), and extend it by adding additional cases:

```
function validate ($rule_bag, $input) {
    $flag = true;
    $error_bag = [];
    foreach ($rule_bag as $item => $rules){
        $rules = is_array($rules) ? $rules : array_filter(explode(',', $rules));
        foreach($rules as $rule){
            $rule = trim($rule);
            switch(mb_strtolower(trim($rule))){
                case 'required': {
                    // checking isset then empty to be compatible with php <= 5.4
                    if (!isset($input[$item]) || empty($input[$item]))
                    {
                        $flag = false;
                        !isset($error_bag[$item])?$error_bag[$item]=[]:null;
                        $error_bag[$item][] = $rule;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    if (isset($input[$item])){
                        try {
                            if (!preg_match($rule, $input[$item])){
                                $flag = false;
                                !isset($error_bag[$item])?$error_bag[$item]=[]:null;
                                !isset($error_bag[$item]['regex'])?$error_bag[$item]['regex']=[]:null;
                                $error_bag[$item]['regex'][] = $rule;
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception $e){
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $flag ? $flag : $error_bag;
}
```